# VBA - Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon"",True)" not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that hides the ribbon, headings, tabs, scrollbar, etc. and a macro that unhides everything again. However, I'm having trouble with showing the Ribbon again. The following line does not work for me:

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
```

I've tried running the command in a separate macro, but I can't bring back the Ribbon again. I can't press CTRL + F1 and in the options menu the Ribbon section is completely empty. The only way to bring it back, is to open a new document, that seems to rest it. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

```
Sub UI()
Worksheets("MAIN").Activate

With ActiveWindow
    .DisplayHeadings = False
    .DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
    .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
    .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False
End With

With Application
    .ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
    .DisplayStatusBar = False
    .DisplayFormulaBar = False
End With
End Sub
```

Here is the macro that unhides everything

```
Sub UI_Reset()
Worksheets("MAIN").Activate

With ActiveWindow
    .DisplayHeadings = True
    .DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
    .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
    .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
End With

With Application
    .ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
    .DisplayFormulaBar = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked the Trust Center?  Excel 4 macros are now disabled by default.

Comment: Running it in 64bit Excel365 working flawless. Wich version is yours?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I've tried turning on the Excel 4 options, but it didn't solve it. I can hide the UI so the False options works, it is just the True expression that sometimes fails.

Comment: @ALeXceL I'm running Excel365 64bit as well.

I tried running the macro in a new workbook, it works fine. For some reason it just doesn't work in my original workbook. if it continues I could just copy it all over, I'm just "worried" it would happen again in the future.

Comment: @DennisChristiansen Open a clean Excel session: Win + R, type EXCEL /safemode and open the 'stubborn' workbook. This might shed some light on your assessment.

Comment: @ALeXceL yes, that does solve the problem. But I still haven't figured out how to unhide the Ribbon in VBA with ExecuteExcel4Macro